# How can I return data with a timestamp and how to filter it?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp

I'm completely new to SQL and I'm struggling. I need to run a query from the dates mentioned below and split the timestamped data into shift hours 6-13:59, 14-21:59 and 22 - 05:59. I need to see how many shipments have been sent in between those hours. I came up with something like this, but it doesn't seem to work.

When I put the date without the timestamp the data gets returned, but I want to have only those rows returned that have been sent in between 6 - 14. The SDG table includes a timestamp, so I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
select s1.date, k.su, count(distinct s1.nr) AMO_SHIP2021
from sdg s1 , client k
where s1.clientnr in ('1')
and s1.date between '01.12.2021 06:00:00' and '14.12.2021 13:59:59'
and s1.function in ('20')
and k.nr = s1.clientnr
group by s1.date, k.su, s1.function
```

Comment: Please use modern join syntax instead of old SQL from the 1980s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post the table structure there. Generally, if your column is of Date type you need to operate dates using `BETWEEN` with dates and not strings

```
s1.date BETWEEN to_date('01.12.2021 06:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND
to_date('14.12.2021 13:59:59', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Refer in your search to FORMAT MODEL.

`to_date('string date', 'format model')`

Comment: Unfortunately, not exactly like that as it'll return **ORA-01849 error**. If you use HH format mask, then you have to specify AM/PM, otherwise Oracle can't tell what you meant to do. Your first "date" is OK (at it represents 06:00AM, but 13:59 is **wrong** as - according to format mask you used - hours must be between 1 and 12 (and 13 isn't really between these two).

Comment: Thank you a lot, that helped me!

Is it possible to return the timestamp between those hours for each date from 01.12.2021 until 14.12.2021? If I put between operator, I'm going to get all the timestamp in between those dates, right, because the timestamp is in between. How can I return the timestamp from 06:00:00 to 13:59:59 for each date without the higher timestamps?

Comment: @Littlefoot Thanks. I added `HH24` since OP has times like `13:59:59`

Comment: @vegandu I think you asking something  you don't want to do. If you're looking for a specific timestamps, you would use `s1.date IN (to_date('14.12.2021 13:59:59', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('01.12.2021 06:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))`

Comment: @T.S Alright, thank you so much!